# which way is better to write add method on a singly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I see 2 youtube videos showing an add at end method as such

```
public void insertFirstLink(String bookName, int millionsSold) {
        Link newLink = new Link(bookName, millionsSold);
        newLink.next = firstLink;
        firstLink = newLink;
    }
```

This looks nice and clean, but I went through another tutorial that does this

```
public void insert(int x) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(x, head);
        } else {
            Node current = head;

            while (current.getNext() != null) {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
            Node newNode = new Node(x, null);
            current.setNext(newNode);
        }
    }
```

why would I ever use the 2nd one since its longer and traverses the list just to add to the end. I am new to linked lists and am confused as to why so many people write it differently, every tutorial I saw was using a different technique. I am mainly studying this to be able to answer interview questions so I need to understand all possibilities.

I am also unclear on what the 'head/current/first' node is. In a tutorial he mentioned that head is the first node added, and becomes the next added node, so eventually the 'head' node is the last node right? when he printed his list it was in reverse.

Comment: The two methods don't do the same. The first inserts the new element at first position, the second adds it to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method inserts a node at the current position (which it appears to be maintaining as a pointer to the end of the list).  The second inserts a node at the end, but without maintaining a tail pointer, so it must first traverse the list until it finds the ending node, and then put the new node there.

Whether the first version or the second is "more correct" is more a matter of your specific software requirements.  They are both correct; they just do the same thing in different ways.  While this example seems especially trivial, it will not be as trivial when you're trying to choose between, say, a Skip List and a Binary Tree.

Comment: firstLink is the first node or last node added according to the tutorial, which confused me. If I add 10 nodes, than firstLink would be the 10th position I believe. In that sense its always adding to the end isn't it?. When you say external state, what do you mean, do you mean the method is apart of the Node and not apart of a LinkedList class which keeps the 'head' position

Comment: thanks, I am still not 100% complete but coming closer. Both of them add to the 'end' of the list no matter what right? if an interviewer asks me to make an add to end method both would be acceptable? I don't get why you said the first method adds to the current position, isn't the current position ALWAYS going to be the last position because head's value is the last value added. Is this how 90% of people would write it?

Comment: There is no "this is how x percent would write it."  It all depends on your software requirements.  For example, how would you add a node to the end of a singly-linked list that didn't have a tail pointer?

Comment: I think I am starting to get it. The first method uses a 'tail' pointer which changes every time you add a node to it. The second method uses a constant 'head' pointer which does not change, and so you have to traverse to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the second way of doing things is that an add method is generally assumed to put the element at the end of the list. If you play with [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) you'll see that elements are printed in the order they are added. It is important for ArrayList and LinkedList to behave the same way.

One way to optimize the second piece of code would be to store a pointer to the tail of the list as well as one to the head so that [adds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28E%29) and [pushes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#push%28E%29) both take O(1) time. If, however, ordering doesn't matter in your data structure, then you should use the first method.

**EDIT:** To clarify, for an "add" you have to use the second method (or some variation) in order for it to be an add, while for a "push" you have to use something similar to the first method; but there is no reason your class cannot have both.

Comment: @CatznDogz I think in your code, Link and Node serve the same purpose, just named differently. If node has an add method, that means the Node class contains some of the logic. This is not necessary for lists but may be helpful for trees or more complicated data structures. Your second code example just uses getters and setters on Node which is different from having an add method. Getters and setters are generally considered good practice in Java (as I'm sure you know), but are used less often on private inner classes. Hope that helps.